# Is there a way to git clone to a commit (url)

Tags: git

Is it possible to do something like

`git clone https://github.com/alberttwong/project.git#ABCDE123`

with ABCDE123 is the commit hash.  As far as I know, you can only url to a branch or tag.

Comment: I think thats not possible. You can only clone a branch directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly clone till a commit hash but can checkout to the specific commit

```
git clone https://github.com/alberttwong/project.git
cd project
git checkout ABCDE123
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't confuse cloning a repository with checking out a specific revision.**

That said, you can definitely accomplish what you want, but the process is more complicated and it really only yields value if the repository is EXTREMELY LARGE and the full history of the commit is small in comparison:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/alberttwong/project.git
git fetch origin ABCDE123
```

Or, **if you are only interested in fetching limited history** then use:

```
git fetch --depth 1 origin ABCDE123
```

The you checkout such commit:

```
git checkout ABCDE123
```